# Facebook realtime update callback POST

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-authentication

Is it possible to make a POST in a wall of a user after a Realtime Update, automatically?

**Example**: The user makes a post in his wall, then Facebook fire an event and send the object data to the url we specified in the realtime updates dashboard. After we process the data the callback url makes a notification/post in the user wall.
Is this possible?
I've been watching the documentation but I'm not figuring out how to get the access_token to make the post.

Regards,
Elkas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the access token in your own database and use that - for some types of publishing you can also use the app access token to publish

Be careful you're not violating policy if you're uploading content without direct user interaction, the app may be removed very quickly if that's the case